# Where can I learn about semantic analysis?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics

I've been working on a semantic analysis pass for my own customary language for a little while now without much success. But if I search for any such things on Google, then the vast majority of the links are uselses university course materials, or academic papers, or just completely unrelated processes, for example semantic analysis of English text, rather than useful knowledge.

I've also looked for the legendary Dragon Book, but I read that it really does not contain much in this regard (and also is way out of my price range on Amazon right now).

Any recommendations as to where I can find materials for this specific phase of compilation?

Comment: Benjamin Pierce has two good books on type checking.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic analysis is a blanket term covering many simple steps inside a compiler.

It usually consists of the following:

- Syntax sugar and/or macro expansion pass to simplify the further analysis
- Identifier resolution and renaming. I.e., each name is turned into a fully qualified identifier, each locally scoped identifier is given a unique name
- Type checking (either type inference or type propagation)
- Constraint checks
- Various sanity checks (i.e., "if a non-void function returns a value", or "if a variable used before initialisation")

The current trend is to try to confine all the constraint checks into the type system instead of having separate passes. A generic and powerful typing algorithm suitable for many different languages is [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner). Although it might look complicated, in fact it is easier to implement than a dumb type propagation (as in C or Java), if you do it the right way.

One very generic and simple trick for doing both complex typing and arbitrary semantic checks is to walk over your AST and emit a flat sequence of Prolog (in some cases even Datalog) expressions which you can feed to a simple Prolog interpreter and get your whole AST constraints system solved.